# Nodejs Socket.io getting user from on("connection") event

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Is there a way to determine a user from a socket.io connection event?

The following code is used to get a user object from the front end currently:

```
io.on("connection", async (socket: Socket) => {
  socket.on("user-joined", (user) => {
    console.log("front end says hi", user);
    connectedUsers.push(user);
  });
});
```

What I would like to know is if there's a way to pass the user right away in the connection event, so I don't have to listen for a follow up 'user-joined' message?

On the client side it seems we can pass `auth` along with the connection.

From https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-initialization/#auth

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io({
  auth: {
    user: "abcd"
  }
});
```

The solution would look something like:

```
io.on("connection", async (socket: Socket) => {
  console.log("front end says hi", socket.handshake.auth); // prints { user: "abcd" }
});
```

Can I pass data with along with the "connection" message to identify the user that is connecting?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to identify the user in the initial connection event.

To start: the client will have to initialize a socket connection with an options param. The options should include an `auth` property that specifies the user.

For example on the client side:

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io({
  auth: {
    user: "abcd"
  }
});
```

On the server side we can read the `auth` data in the the connection event handler:

```
io.on("connection", async (socket: Socket) => {
  console.log("front end says hi", socket.handshake.auth); 
  // prints "front end says hi", { user: "abcd" }
});
```

You may also find this link to the official docs helpful: https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-initialization/#auth